# How to query multiple conditions in pouchDB/couchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

I want a query in pouchDB which returns me all entries where property x is between 1 and 5 AND where property z equals 'test'.

I wrote a query which returns me all entries between 1 and 5 but I have no idea how I can extend my query to also consider the equals condition.

```
var options = {
    include_docs: true,
    startkey: [1],
    endkey: [5]
};

var query = function (entry) {
    emit([entry.x]);
};

database.query(query, options)
    .then(function (result) { /* ... */ })
    .catch(function (err) { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could emit the key as:

```
emit([entry.z, entry.x]);
```

and then search:

```
http://.......view?startkey=["test",1]&endkey=["test",5]
```

Bear in mind that you cannot execute a query with both parts of the key being constrained by a range. Here is some documentation on searching: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html